# Tag Rename: [Republic-of-Ireland] to [Ireland]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I'd like to discuss renaming the tag [republic-of-ireland](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/republic-of-ireland) to [ireland](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ireland). As provided for in Article 4 of the [Constitution of Ireland (Bunreacht na hÉireann)](https://www.constitution.ie/Documents/Bhunreacht_na_hEireann_web.pdf). To quote:

> The name of the State is Éire, or, in the English language, Ireland.

Nó i nGaeilge:

> Is Stát ceannasach, neamhspleách, daonlathach Éire.

The description "Republic of Ireland" is just that, a description and not a name. It is provided for in the [Republic of Ireland Act (1948)](http://www.irishstatutebook.ie/eli/1948/act/22/enacted/en/html) but it does not replace or supplant the official name of the state. Within the context of politics there is a small likelihood of the tag being confused with questions referring instead to the island of Ireland and these issues can be addressed through editing. Whilst we're at it adding the Synonyms "republic-of-Ireland" and "Éire".

Thoughts/Opinions appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

The thing with [ireland](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ireland) is that it's ambiguous; it can refer to the 
Republic of Ireland, Northern Ireland, or the geographical island of Ireland.

By using the name [republic-of-ireland](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/republic-of-ireland) it's very clear what it refers to. This could also be clarified in the tag description, but in my experience people don't read those. We should always make the tag meaning clear from just the name whenever possible, as it will prevent mistagging (and even then it'll probably be mistagged).

This is also the same approach that Wikipedia takes, by the way; [Ireland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ireland) refers to the island and its history, [Republic of Ireland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_of_Ireland) to the country commonly known as "Ireland".

Comment: But the problem with "The Republic of Ireland" is that it is in no way the name of the country being referred to. It seems somewhat unusual not to refer to a country by it's chosen/given name and I'm not aware of any other case where this is done. Figured it was worth soliciting some input. I agree with the clarity argument, in part, Ireland in practice isn't used to refer to Northern Ireland very often, if at all, Ireland as the Island is a valid point but seems like it would be somewhat of an edge case on a politics Q&A site...

Comment: Well, Wikipedia uses that name @HomoTechsual, and a [quick internet search](https://duckduckgo.com/lite/?q=Republic%20of%20Ireland) reveals it's not the only one to do so (the Irish football team is named [Republic of Ireland national football team](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_of_Ireland_national_football_team) for example). I would personally use "Ireland" myself, except in cases where you want to be as clear as possible to *which* Ireland I'm referring to (such as tag names). Alternatives might be [tag:country-of-ireland] or something to that effect, but IMHO that's rather ugly.

Comment: I accept that there are plenty of examples however the fact still remains that the tag refers to Ireland using a description and not a name like the other tags referring to countries. Republic of Ireland simply isn't a name for Ireland in any way.

Comment: Equally there are notable examples going the other way. [United Nations](http://www.un.org/esa/agenda21/natlinfo/countr/ireland/), [European Union](https://europa.eu/european-union/about-eu/countries/member-countries/ireland_en), [OECD](http://www.oecd.org/ireland/)

Comment: @HomoTechsual Well, the "Republic of Ireland Act" you already mentioned in your question provides "Republic of Ireland" as a "description". [Wikipedia has some context on that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_of_Ireland_Act_1948#Republic_of_Ireland_Description). Either way, I don't this it's all that important, what is more important is clarity and lack of ambiguity, and that's what "Republic of Ireland" offers.

Comment: fair point. It's possible that it won't change for those reasons. Equally I'd kind of like it "on the record" what the reasons are if that's what this meta post accomplishes I'm happy either way!

Answer (score 0):

I was one of the two reviewers who [declined this suggested edit](https://politics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/13465), giving the reason "The name "Republic of Ireland" allows us to differentiate between the sovereign state and the geographical location, it should thus not be changed".

To expand on my reasoning, the aim of tag excerpts are primarily for usage guidance, the casual poster is unlikely to have read the Constitution of Ireland, but if asking about some Irish matters are likely able to differentiate between whether their question applies to Ireland or Northern Ireland. However some questions may refer to both Ireland and Northern Ireland, in this case for ease of use we differentiate with the tag [republic-of-ireland](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/republic-of-ireland) and [ireland](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ireland). I could not see sufficient justification in renaming it according to the constitutional name as opposed to a name that the common user is unlikely to confuse for the whole island.